# How to debug “network is unreachable” error for a virtual Linux interface

Tags: linux, networking, routing, tunnel, kernel-module

I have only loopback (lo) and virtual interface in the system. I closed all other interfaces. I also stopped firewall, selinux and iptables. I want to ping an IP address in route table, but I get the "network is unreachable" error as below.

What I want to learn how I should approach such a problem? dmesg or system messages show nothing. Why is an interface unreachable and how can I find out the problem.

Thanks in advance

```
# ping 172.99.0.2
PING 172.99.0.2 (172.99.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable

# ifconfig 
gtp1: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 0
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 479  bytes 40888 (40.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 479  bytes 40888 (40.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.99.0.2      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 gtp1

# find / -name gtp1
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/gtp1
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/gtp1
/sys/class/net/gtp1
/sys/devices/virtual/net/gtp1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot ping this address though it is in the routing table since the interface that is assigned for this route does not have an IP for itself.
So your host cannot send a packet there.

In general, when you want to learn about network I recommend starting to play around with Wireshark/tcpdump. This way you will see how packet flow, how addressing works, what low-level traffic you have etc.
E.g. try to understand every packet that shows up when connection with a browser to (e.g.) httpbin.org/ip.